# add UDID in current provisioning profile

Tags: ios, udid

I have a distribution provisioning profile with 1 device already.
Now there are a couple more devices want to be added to this project.

How do I do to add them in without creating a new distribution provision profile?

I click edit provision profile, there is no device list. just "Generate" button. but for development profile, I do see devices list on it. My question is for production profile. After I submit the app to Apple store, the "In Review" status takes a long time. During this period I have made some changes to my project and want testing it on couple iPhones. I knew I can change the code signing to development profile. Is there a better way?

Comment: distribution or developer provisioning profile?

Comment: distribution profile. But I want to test my app in my team also.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to find out your UDID then visit here: http://whatsmyudid.com/

If you already know your UDID then go to the Devices section of your iOS Provisioning Portal and click "Add Devices":

[image]

Enter in your Device Name and UDID (it's best to copy and paste) and hit Submit:
[image]

- Once you successfully add your device's UDID, edit the provisioning
  profile to which you want to add the device.
- Select the device from the list
- Click on generate.
- Download the new profile.

Enjoy :)

Comment: I guess you copy this answer from others. I had already read this post. I think it was old version interface. in new version, I click edit provision profile, there is no device list. just "Generate" button.

Comment: I guess you copy this answer from others. I had already read this post. I click edit this production provisioning profile, there is no device list. just "Generate" button. but for development profile, I do see device list on it. My question is for production profile. The "In Review" statu after submit the app takes a long time, during thie period I have made some changes on my project and want testing it on couple Iphones. I knew I can change the code signing to development profile. Is there better way to do so whithout change it to development profile?

Comment: @vinay can you update the answer with the latest way to do it? Cant See the Add UDID option. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

in [iOS Provision Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action)

(1) add the UDID to the Devices

(2) select the profile in Distribution and edit it. In edit page, check the device you added in (1).

Comment: can you update the answer with the latest way to do it? Cant See the Add UDID option. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2018, just did this today:
Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/

1. Add the devices in the "Devices" Menu
2. In the "Provisioning Profiles" Menu, click on "Development" -> select the profile -> "Edit" -> Scroll down, activate the devices you added

**Screenshot of developer portal**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2):

A lot of updates in UI of `iOS Provision Portal` so I just re-introduce base on new interface. I also newbie in iOS development so it takes me a lot of time to find out.

1. Open `iPhone` in `Device` section in sidebar.

   https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/iphone
2. Click `+` icon in top right to add new UDID to your account.

[image]

3. Enter Name & UDID (If you don't know your device UDID, visit [this site](http://whatsmyudid.com/) to know how to get it)

[image]

4. Click `Development` of `Provisioning Profiles` section in sidebar.
   https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/limited
5. Select your `iOS Provisioning Profiles` and `Edit` it.
6. Select added device name in `Devices` section to add to `Provisioning Profiles`
   [image]
7. `Genarate` & `Download` again.