# sending an App without having insight in the code

Tags: ios, xcode, export

I would like a friend to test my App on his iPhone, I am in Germany and he is in France.

Is there any way that he can test my (with Xcode) developed App on his iPhone, so that he cannot see the code behind to protect myself from piratery? So kinda like P-Files in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get UUID of your friends device and add it to your provision profile. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257577/add-udid-in-current-provisioning-profile) for same.

You should generate ipa file and share it with your friend. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode/47940681) for generating ipa.

Comment: wc. I teach iOS development and maching learning with python in one to one sessions. Let me know if anybody is interested. :) :)