# Can one distribute an unpublished react-native ios app?

Tags: ios, react-native

Is it possible to build a react-native ios app and distribute it 'privately'? For example if one has a client and the client require the app not to be publicly available on the app store?

Comment: Thanks @Ajaysaini it is exactly the answer I needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two thing.

1. You can create build using adHoc provisioning profile and share with the client.  (Using apple's developer account)(Upto 100 devices of each family)
2. You can distribute privately using Apple's Developer enterprise program for in house distribution. these type of apps will not be visible to public.  (No limit but cost $299 per year)

Read more : https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/

here a decent article about distributing app using the enterprise account : https://medium.com/apps-studio/distributing-enterprise-ios-app-in-house-without-mdm-3ed015009893

Comment: You should be-aware that there are limits on the number of devices that you can use with an `ad-hoc` profile where as an `enterprise` profile does not suffer from those limitations, however an enterprise account costs $299 compared to a developer account which costs $99.

Comment: You can also publish the app as a B2B app using a standard developer program membership. The client would then purchase the app via the Volume purchase program and distribute it to their users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But make sure you have a developer account.

1: Make sure you are building a release `ipa`,
Go to  project, edit schema and then select your schema and select release mode.

2: Make sure you change your location of the js bundle, here is a good post on how to do  both steps.

https://medium.com/react-native-development/deploying-a-react-native-app-for-ios-pt-1-a79dfd15acb8

3: After these steps. You need add the UDID of that client in your developer account.
[add UDID in current provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257577/add-udid-in-current-provisioning-profile)

4: Then you need to download the `Manual Profiles`

this link has everything you need.
https://ioscodesigning.com/generating-code-signing-files/

5: After all the hectic job (when you are doing it for the first time).
   in `xcode` go Select Product > Archive and then `adhoc` and next next... You can uncheck the bitcode. And after few minutes you `xcode` will generate `.ipa` file for you.

6: When you finally generate your `.ipa`, you can upload it here. https://www.diawi.com/

7: For all `UDID's` which are present in your developer account, those can download it and use it :)

NOTE: When you debug your app from your iPhone, that iPhones UDID is added automatically, and always download `Manual Profiles` before archiving to receive the latest `udid's` and it will only support upto 100 devices. and if you want more, you can upgrade your plan to `enterprise`